# Verisign SSL Certificates are expensive- are they worth the money and is there a reasonable alternative?

Tags: linux

UK prices for the cheapest verisign certificate are £259+VAT per year. This is quite a lot for something that is a 128bit string that I can make on my own computer. I understand that this value is in the 'brand'- but is there a cheaper alternative, and if so, what are the pitfalls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several alternative certificate providers out there. What exactly are you looking for?

With Verisign - or any other cert provider - you're not so much paying for the "string of bits", or to a lesser degree, the "brand" as you are for the "[web of trust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_certificate)"; peoples browsers will trust certificates issued by major certificate providers without flagging up an "error" to the person browsing the site. If you self-sign certificates then people will see an error because their browser will not know if it can "trust" the certificate being offered or not. How much of a problem this is for you depends on your audience for the site (e.g. self signed certs may be acceptable for internal user for an "employees only" site.)

I use certificates issued from [digicert](http://www.digicert.com/) on the sites I manage for my employer, and I should think you'll find them cheaper... but you really do need to think about the problem you're solving and the cost of solving it properly vs. the cost of not doing so before you can evaluate any price you're offered.

Comment: I believe he wants customer acceptance and browser integration. I couldn't name any real technical need for a "proper" SSL certificate.

Comment: Yeah I re-did my answer along those lines...